# How to trace this C recursive program

Tags: c, trace

I'm new to the topic of recursion and having a hard time conceptualizing the trace for the C program below. Any assistance in providing resources or an explanation on how to trace it is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int multiply(int x, int y);

int exponent(int x, int y);
int exponent(int x, int y) {
    if (y == 0){
        return 1;
    } else {
        int i = exponent(x,y-1);
        int n = multiply(x,i); 
        return n;
    }
}

int multiply(int x, int y) {

if (y == 0 || x == 0){
    return 0;
} 

if (y > 0) {
    return x + multiply(x,y-1); 
}
else {
    return -x + multiply(x,y+1); 
}
}

int main() {
printf("3^5 = %i\n", exponent(3, 5));
}
```

Comment: Either step through the code in your debugger or add some printf statements to help you see what is going as the program executes.

Comment: Seriously: take a piece of paper and a pen; and then start "running" the program manually for (small) numbers. Then add "trace" statements into the code and "really" run it. Of course, that is a bit of work; but when you are really interested in "getting at recursion", there is no better way than "doing it yourself".

Comment: Search "recursion" on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematically, recursion is similar to mathematical induction. When we use recursion, keep in mind what is the base case and what is the recursive call. There is practically not much more to investigate. Here I have added appropriate debug statement so that you can see how the recursion "builds up" by recursive function calls that eventually are interrupted by reaching the base case, which interrupts the recursion.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int multiply(int x, int y);

int exponent(int x, int y);
int j = 0;
int exponent(int x, int y) {
    if (y == 0){
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf("depth:%d x:%d y:%d\n", j, x, y);
        j++;
        int i = exponent(x,y-1);

        int n = multiply(x,i);
        return n;
    }
}
int k = 0;
int multiply(int x, int y) {

    if (y == 0 || x == 0){
        return 0;
    }

    if (y > 0) {
        printf("depth multiply:%d x:%d y:%d\n", k, x, y);
        k++;
        return x + multiply(x,y-1);
    }
    else {
        printf("depth multiply:%d x:%d y:%d\n", k, x, y);
        k++;
        return -x + multiply(x,y+1);
    }
}

int main() {
    printf("3^5 = %i\n", exponent(3, 5));
}
```

Output

```
depth:0 x:3 y:5
depth:1 x:3 y:4
depth:2 x:3 y:3
depth:3 x:3 y:2
depth:4 x:3 y:1
depth multiply:0 x:3 y:1
depth multiply:1 x:3 y:3
depth multiply:2 x:3 y:2
depth multiply:3 x:3 y:1
depth multiply:4 x:3 y:9
depth multiply:5 x:3 y:8
depth multiply:6 x:3 y:7
depth multiply:7 x:3 y:6
depth multiply:8 x:3 y:5
depth multiply:9 x:3 y:4
depth multiply:10 x:3 y:3
depth multiply:11 x:3 y:2
depth multiply:12 x:3 y:1
depth multiply:13 x:3 y:27
depth multiply:14 x:3 y:26
depth multiply:15 x:3 y:25
depth multiply:16 x:3 y:24
depth multiply:17 x:3 y:23
depth multiply:18 x:3 y:22
depth multiply:19 x:3 y:21
depth multiply:20 x:3 y:20
depth multiply:21 x:3 y:19
depth multiply:22 x:3 y:18
depth multiply:23 x:3 y:17
depth multiply:24 x:3 y:16
depth multiply:25 x:3 y:15
depth multiply:26 x:3 y:14
depth multiply:27 x:3 y:13
depth multiply:28 x:3 y:12
depth multiply:29 x:3 y:11
depth multiply:30 x:3 y:10
depth multiply:31 x:3 y:9
depth multiply:32 x:3 y:8
depth multiply:33 x:3 y:7
depth multiply:34 x:3 y:6
depth multiply:35 x:3 y:5
depth multiply:36 x:3 y:4
depth multiply:37 x:3 y:3
depth multiply:38 x:3 y:2
depth multiply:39 x:3 y:1
depth multiply:40 x:3 y:81
depth multiply:41 x:3 y:80
depth multiply:42 x:3 y:79
depth multiply:43 x:3 y:78
depth multiply:44 x:3 y:77
depth multiply:45 x:3 y:76
depth multiply:46 x:3 y:75
depth multiply:47 x:3 y:74
depth multiply:48 x:3 y:73
depth multiply:49 x:3 y:72
depth multiply:50 x:3 y:71
depth multiply:51 x:3 y:70
depth multiply:52 x:3 y:69
depth multiply:53 x:3 y:68
depth multiply:54 x:3 y:67
depth multiply:55 x:3 y:66
depth multiply:56 x:3 y:65
depth multiply:57 x:3 y:64
depth multiply:58 x:3 y:63
depth multiply:59 x:3 y:62
depth multiply:60 x:3 y:61
depth multiply:61 x:3 y:60
depth multiply:62 x:3 y:59
depth multiply:63 x:3 y:58
depth multiply:64 x:3 y:57
depth multiply:65 x:3 y:56
depth multiply:66 x:3 y:55
depth multiply:67 x:3 y:54
depth multiply:68 x:3 y:53
depth multiply:69 x:3 y:52
depth multiply:70 x:3 y:51
depth multiply:71 x:3 y:50
depth multiply:72 x:3 y:49
depth multiply:73 x:3 y:48
depth multiply:74 x:3 y:47
depth multiply:75 x:3 y:46
depth multiply:76 x:3 y:45
depth multiply:77 x:3 y:44
depth multiply:78 x:3 y:43
depth multiply:79 x:3 y:42
depth multiply:80 x:3 y:41
depth multiply:81 x:3 y:40
depth multiply:82 x:3 y:39
depth multiply:83 x:3 y:38
depth multiply:84 x:3 y:37
depth multiply:85 x:3 y:36
depth multiply:86 x:3 y:35
depth multiply:87 x:3 y:34
depth multiply:88 x:3 y:33
depth multiply:89 x:3 y:32
depth multiply:90 x:3 y:31
depth multiply:91 x:3 y:30
depth multiply:92 x:3 y:29
depth multiply:93 x:3 y:28
depth multiply:94 x:3 y:27
depth multiply:95 x:3 y:26
depth multiply:96 x:3 y:25
depth multiply:97 x:3 y:24
depth multiply:98 x:3 y:23
depth multiply:99 x:3 y:22
depth multiply:100 x:3 y:21
depth multiply:101 x:3 y:20
depth multiply:102 x:3 y:19
depth multiply:103 x:3 y:18
depth multiply:104 x:3 y:17
depth multiply:105 x:3 y:16
depth multiply:106 x:3 y:15
depth multiply:107 x:3 y:14
depth multiply:108 x:3 y:13
depth multiply:109 x:3 y:12
depth multiply:110 x:3 y:11
depth multiply:111 x:3 y:10
depth multiply:112 x:3 y:9
depth multiply:113 x:3 y:8
depth multiply:114 x:3 y:7
depth multiply:115 x:3 y:6
depth multiply:116 x:3 y:5
depth multiply:117 x:3 y:4
depth multiply:118 x:3 y:3
depth multiply:119 x:3 y:2
depth multiply:120 x:3 y:1
3^5 = 243
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time out to help.